# How to load only html (and skip the media files)

Tags: php, http, curl, web-crawler

I'm optimizing my simple web crawler (currently using PHP/curl_multi).

Goal is to crawl entire website while being smart, and skiping the non-html content. I tried using nobody, and send only HEAD requests, but that doesn't seem to work on every website (some servers don't support HEAD), causing exec to pause for long times (sometimes much longer than loading page itself).

Is there any other way to get page type without downloading the entire content or force CURL to abandon download if file isn't html?

(Writing my own http client is not an option, cause I'm intending to use CURL functions as cookies and ssl later on).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way to do this is use

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, 'curlHeaderCallback');
```

The callback will accept 2 parameters - first CURL Handle, second - header. It'll be called each time new header arrives.

```
$acceptable=array('application/xhtml+xml',
'application/xml', 'text/plain',
'text/xml', 'text/html');

function curlHeaderCallback($resURL, $strHeader) { 
    global $acceptable;
    if (stripos($strHeader,'content-type')===0) {
        $type=strtolower(trim(array_shift(explode(';',array_pop(explode(':',$strHeader))))));
        if (!in_array($type,$acceptable))
            return 0;
    }
    return strlen($strHeader);
```

}

Comment: you should accept your own answer because it's the most correct.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but I see `CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION`. I bet you could progressively read the response to look for the `content-type` header and probably [curl_close](http://www.php.net/curl_close)() the handle if you aren't interested in whats being downloaded.

```
CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION     The name of a callback function
where the callback function takes three parameters. The first is the
cURL resource, the second is a file-descriptor resource, and the 
third is length. Return the string containing the data.
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: Almost perfect. Two major problems with this: first - you're unable to curl_close() from callback function - it only gives warning message. Second - there is no way to tell which curl handle called the function (important when using curl_multi). But your hint pointed me towards right answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [fsockopen](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)?

You could open a socket to the remote page, and read in only what is necessary. Once you have the `Content-Type` header identified, you can close the connection.

```
<?php
$type = 'Unknown';
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
    $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
    $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $out);

    $in = '';
    while (!feof($fp)) {
        $in .= fgets($fp, 128);
        if ( preg_match( '/Content-Type: (.+)\n/i', $in, &$matches ) ) {
            $type = $matches[1];
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
echo $type;
?>
```

Comment: As I said - writing my own http client is too much work for now. Many pages will not even open if I haven't got my cookies right, not mentioning ssl and other things like redirecting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```php
<?php
$handle = curl_init('http://www.google.com');
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
$result = curl_exec($handle);
$type = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE);
if(strpos($type, 'text/html') !== false) {
    echo 'The URL is an HTML page.';
}
?>
```

Comment: in this code you're actually downloading entire page before checking it's type.